# Filtering Pandas DataFrame for percentage of missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with quite a few missing values that are being represented by `np.nan`. I would like to be able to return the rows in the DataFrame having more than 80% of their values missing.

So far I have tried the following:

```
data.loc[lambda x: (len(x.isna()) / len(x.columns)) > .8]
```

but this is apparently not how `loc` works when passed a lambda function. My interpretation of this was that Pandas was simply running a loop over each row and applying the function, expecting a `True` or `False` value in return indicating to keep or discard the row, respectively. Essentially a filter function.

Is there a Pandas way of achieving what I want or shall I resort to plain python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dropna` with `thresh` (thresh :  Require that many non-NA values.)

```
df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns)*0.8)
```

Update :

```
df[(df.isna().sum(1)/df.shape[1]).gt(0.8)]
```

Comment: Thank you. This will definitely be helpful with what I intend to do later, however this does the opposite of what I want initially. I want to display the rows having at least 80% of their data missing whereas this displays those with at least 80% of their data present. So rather I'm interested in the rows thrown away by `df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns)*0.2)`

Comment: @tomasbasham ok I will updat e

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much